# Connections between spectral geometry and critical point/Morse theory

Tags: reference-request, sp.spectral-theory, knot-theory, hyperbolic-geometry, morse-theory

I am researching electrostatic knot theory, which is essentially the theory of harmonic functions on knot complements. I want to understand the number of critical points of the electric potential, their indices, and their placement. I also want to understand how these phenomena change under knot isotopy.

In particular, hyperbolic knots have a unique complete metric of constant curvature -1, and thus possess a well-defined Laplacian operator. There are a number of papers discussing the spectral theory of the Laplacian for hyperbolic knots, like [Futer, Kalfagianni, Purcell (2009)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0901.0119.pdf). Harmonic functions (AKA the kernel of the Laplacian) also have special critical point sets, notably critical points of harmonic functions are all saddle nodes. However, after some searching, I couldn't find anything that relates the critical sets of harmonic functions to the spectrum of the Laplacian, even outside the context of knot theory. I suspect this could be a potentially fruitful path to follow, but does anyone here have any suggestions of where to look?